# Fix Chocolatey "Access is Denied"

Tags: chocolatey

I just installed Chocolatey for the first time using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw9WX.png) command in an admin cmd:

> @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
> -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object
> System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
> && SET "PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin"

**Admin cmd output:**

```
Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
Getting Chocolatey from https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/0.10.13.
Extracting C:\Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\CurrentUser\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall...
Installing chocolatey on this machine
Creating ChocolateyInstall as an environment variable (targeting 'Machine')
  Setting ChocolateyInstall to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey'
WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
  before you can use choco.
Restricting write permissions to Administrators
We are setting up the Chocolatey package repository.
The packages themselves go to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib'
  (i.e. C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName).
A shim file for the command line goes to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin'
  and points to an executable in 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\yourPackageName'.

Creating Chocolatey folders if they do not already exist.

WARNING: You can safely ignore errors related to missing log files when
  upgrading from a version of Chocolatey less than 0.9.9.
  'Batch file could not be found' is also safe to ignore.
  'The system cannot find the file specified' - also safe.
WARNING: Not setting tab completion: Profile file does not exist at
'C:\Users\CurrentUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'.
WARNING: Unable to run Chocolately at this time.  It is likely that .Net Framework installation requires a system reboot
Chocolatey (choco.exe) is now ready.
You can call choco from anywhere, command line or powershell by typing choco.
Run choco /? for a list of functions.
You may need to shut down and restart powershell and/or consoles
 first prior to using choco.
Ensuring chocolatey commands are on the path
Ensuring chocolatey.nupkg is in the lib folder
```

**After restarting my cmd I still can't access choco commands:**

[image]

There does not seem to be documentation on why this happens. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: @JanStanstrup I still don't have a solution to this. I ended up using nuget to get what I need instead. This was for DocFX

Answer (score 48):

run your command prompt as administration then run command "choco install nodejs"

Comment: The description indicates they ran it as administrator. I came here with the same problem as the OP, @Jose De Gouveia's answer helped.

Answer (score 9):

This is related probably to antivirus, in my case was Sophos and needed to add choco as a whitelist

Answer (score 6):

For me works just running terminal on admin mode

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, especially when you don't provide any explanation

Answer (score 3):

Add Choco's directory (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey) for exclusion in Microsoft Defender: Virus and thread protection > Manage settings > Add or remove exclusions > Add an exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved the issue:

1. I launched my cmd as an administrator.
2. I located the chocolatey directory and the HTTPCache directory as well and I deleted them with "rmdir /s /q chocolatey"...(you should find it at the ProgramData folder)
3. Reinstalled the chocolatey again.