# Access denied on ProgramData when installed Sass with Choclatey (in admin powershell)

Tags: css, powershell, sass, chocolatey

I am trying to install the [sass css transpiler](https://sass-lang.com/install) from chocolately. The install fails to fully execute because the executeable can't be compiled into the correct location.

[image]

Note that choco thinks it is installed.

[image]

But running it doesn't work due to the missing executable.
[image]

First off this is not a duplicate of [Fix Chocolatey "Access is Denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600258/fix-chocolatey-access-is-denied) or [Permission denied in chocolatey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908059/permission-denied-in-chocolatey).

In screenshots I've censored my name, they should still be useful.

Things I've checked:

I'm in an administrator shell.

[image: I'm in an administrator shell.]

ExecutionPolicy is AllSigned.

[image: AllSigned]

I only have the one admin account.

[image: I only have the one admin account.]

All users have full permissions in the chocolately directory and al the way down into lbi and bin dirs. I know this is not idea long term but I'm trying a bunch.

[image: Perms]

Bitdefender antivirus hasn't been complaining although it initially did false positive sass with a known common false positive. Howerver I tried exempting sass and chocolately in the settings.

[image: Bitdefender.]

Comment: Go to task manager and make sure the exe file shown in the error message is not running before starting installation.  Windows like to automatically start apps that were running before a shutdown or a reboot.  I think the error message is due to the application running so in can not be changed by the installer.

Comment: The file in the error message doesn't exist. It's a supposed to be a compiler output but the error is the failed write from the compiler. I showed the directory where it's supposed to be. I have now checked but as expected there is nothing there in task manager.

Comment: Did you open task manager as admin?  If you don't you will only see processes that are owned by your account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a package issue. Have you tried to reach out to the maintainer using the 'Contact Maintainer' on the package page?

Comment: I have now. My default assumption that I've done something wrong or am missing something has typically been true whenever I find stubborn setup issues though so it hadn't crossed my mind to do so.